# How to tell if pitch bend is supported

Tags: windows-7, midi

Win7-64:
This is my only midi device:
Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth, deviceid = 0.

Is there any way to tell if midi pitch bend is supported on this device?

Comment: IMO if it's GM, it necessarily supports pitch bend, velocity, and some other basic controls and sysex.

Comment: Ok, I find it is supported on the default builtin software synth, Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth. I had to write a midi program to test it.

Comment: you should post that as an answer; answering your own question is encouraged.  you don't need to post code if you don't want to, but feel free to go into as much detail as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with default device 0 (Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth) and finished my solution using the [C# Midi Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx). Here is the C# code that works with this toolkit. pitchBend is any integer from 0 to 16383. Pitch bend works. You have to turn a note on first (not shown).

```
if(pitchBend > 16383)
    pitchBend = 16383;

int mask = 127;

ChannelMessageBuilder builder = new ChannelMessageBuilder();

// Build pitch bend message;
builder.Command = ChannelCommand.PitchWheel;

// Unpack pitch bend value into two data bytes.
builder.Data1 = pitchBend & mask;
builder.Data2 = pitchBend >> 7;

// Build message.
builder.Build();

ChannelMessage pitchBendMessage = builder.Result;

// Send message (assumes we've created an output device).
outDevice.Send(pitchBendMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Send it notes from an external keyboard with a pitch bend controller

Comment: Don't have that. What would be nice is full technical documentation on the software included with windows. You have to scrounge around on forums and google to find anything if you are lucky.